# I am developing a android application how can i take to the google map by tapping on address? Using Sqlite some of the code is here

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary

```
//function 
private void addOrderValuesToViewItem(long itemId) {
  //cursor variable         
  Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readOrderItem(Long.toString(itemId));
  //condition 
  while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    tvoid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry._ID)));
    //info          
    bookname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_book_name));

    //getting bookstore name from db   
    bookstorename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_book_storename));

    //getting customer name from db   
    customername = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_customername));
    //getting contact from db 
    customercontact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_contact));
    //getting address from db this is where i want to put a hyperlink where user clicks and app takes him to the google map 
    customeraddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_address));
  }

  //cursor variable  
  Cursor cr = db.getBookStore(bookstorename);
  //condition for verifying  
  while (cr.moveToNext()){
    //address      
    bookstoreaddress = cr.getString(3);
    //store      
    bookstorecontact = cr.getString(4);
  }

  //contactinfo 
  tvcontact.setText(bookstorecontact);
  //again this is the address 
  tvaddress.setText(bookstoreaddress);
  //bookinfo   
  tvbookname.setText(bookname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an `OnClickListener` for your `TextView` with address and in that call an `Intent` to maps like

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + yourAddress);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Refer : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents